# Problem installing MongoDB using MacPorts

Tags: mongodb, macports

Im trying to install MongoDB on Snow Leopard using MacPorts, as explained on the MongoDB site (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+OS+X).  However, it's stuck 'building boost'. Nothing's happened for 20 minutes.

The progress from the terminal is attached.  Any help on this would be appreciated.  Im excited to check out MongoDB.

> ```
> $ port install mongodb
> ```
>
> Warning: MacPorts running without privileges. You may be unable to complete certain actions (e.g. install).
>   --->  Computing dependencies for mongodb
>   --->  Dependencies to be installed: boost libpcap pcre ncurses ncursesw readline scons python26 db46 gdbm gettext libiconv gperf openssl sqlite3 tk Xft2 fontconfig freetype pkgconfig xrender xorg-libX11 xorg-bigreqsproto xorg-inputproto xorg-kbproto xorg-libXau xorg-xproto xorg-libXdmcp xorg-util-macros xorg-xcmiscproto xorg-xextproto xorg-xf86bigfontproto xorg-xtrans xorg-renderproto tcl xorg-libXScrnSaver xorg-libXext xorg-scrnsaverproto spidermonkey nspr
>   --->  Fetching boost
>   --->  Attempting to fetch boost_1_42_0.tar.bz2 from superb-west.dl.sourceforge.net/boost
>   --->  Attempting to fetch boost_1_42_0.tar.bz2 from superb-east.dl.sourceforge.net/boost
>   --->  Attempting to fetch boost_1_42_0.tar.bz2 from downloads.sourceforge.net/boost
>   --->  Verifying checksum(s) for boost
>   --->  Extracting boost
>   --->  Applying patches to boost
>   --->  Configuring boost
>   --->  Building boost

Comment: 45 minutes after running the install command I finally have an update.  Now it's '--->  Staging boost into destroot'.  It's taking its time.  I'll let in run overnight and see if it finishes.

Comment: If your not against it, you can get things up and running much more quickly by downloading the binaries.

Comment: thanks kb.  I was able to download MongoDB through the gem but I can't seem to fire up the Mongo server. The command "./mongodb-xxxxxxx/bin/mongod"returns this error: "-bash: ./mongodb-xxxxxxx/bin/mongod: No such file or directory"
I'm trying to install through the binaries but I'm having problems there too (which I'll define in another thread). With attempted installation through MacPorts and the binaries, Im worried I have references to MongoDB in too many folders on my system.

Answer (score 6):

Boost is a pretty big library -- it could take a while to install.

You can run `port` with the verbose flag (or the debug flag) to see details about the progress:

```
$ port -v install mongodb
```

Answer (score 1):

follow following commands

```
sudo port install mongodb
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
sudo chown `id -u` /data/db
```

Answer (score 0):

if you used macports it installs to /opt/local/bin by default

to list the files in this directory type:
 $>> ls /opt/local/bin

if you see mongod, type:
 ./mongod

then check if it's running in the browser at http://0.0.0.0:28017/ or localhost:28017